# Finding The top ranked match in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cursor, rank

I have a situation for which I need guidance/solution.

I have a table which contains the Order as below:

| color | rank |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Green | 3 |
| Yellow | 4 |
| White | 5 |
| Black | 6 |

I have another table like below

| id | ColorValue |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | Red,Yellow |
| ID2 | Green |
| ID3 | White |
| ID4 | Green,Red |
| ID5 | Yellow, White,Black |

Now, the first table defines the selected color based on priority and would like colorValue to be replaced with the color which is ranked highest (1 is high and 6 is lowest).

The output I want is as below:

| id | ColorValue | Value to be replaced |  | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Red,Yellow | Red |  | Red is ranked higher than yellow |
| ID2 | Green | Green |  |  |
| ID3 | White | White |  |  |
| ID4 | Green,Red | Red |  | Red is ranked higher than Green |
| ID5 | Yellow, White,Black | Yellow |  | Yellow is ranked highest among 3 colors |

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log

Comment: Then check my 2nd query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables and use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get the higher ranked color:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, t2.ColorValue, 
       FIRST_VALUE(t1.color) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ColorValue ORDER BY t1.`rank`) Value_to_be_replaced
FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.color, t2.ColorValue)
ORDER BY t2.id
```

This will work in MySql 8.0+.

For prior versions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t2.*,
       (
         SELECT t1.color
         FROM table1 t1
         WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t1.color, t2.ColorValue)
         ORDER BY t1.`rank` LIMIT 1
       ) Value_to_be_replaced
FROM table2 t2
ORDER BY t2.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcf1bcec454b0f25edc60f22373095f8).

Comment: Thanks forpas. Seems to be working well. I need to validate the data but looks fine at this moment. Thank you very much for the quick response and solution.